# How many samples are needed to find a positive case in classification?

Tags: classification, deep-learning, performance

I’m working with segmented cells from thin blood smear images and using deep learning models to classify parasitic and uninfected cells.

I obtained the following values: Accuracy: 0.986, AUC: 0.99, Sensitivity: 0.981, Specificity: 0.992, F1-score: 0.987, MCC: 0.972, TP: 1329 , FN: 26, FP: 11, TN: 1364.

In one of my submissions, I have got a question from a reviewer like this:

Given a system (with p sensitivity, r specificity), how many RBCs need to be analyzed to confidently decide that a person is infected by malaria (given he has q% parasitemia).

With the above reasoning/study, report how many RBCs you need to analyze to confidently decide (statistically significant) a person (with q% parasitemia) is infected or not by the best system that you have developed. Also report by the same system, what is the lower level of parasitemia you can diagnose.

Can anyone suggest me an answer (assuming the degree of parasitemia) since we don't have that measure.